# Install Ubuntu on Macbook Air 6,2

Tags: installation, boot, mac, macbook-air

I have tried to install Ubuntu on a Macbook Air 6,2 without any success.

I installed refit and from within macos deceased the mac partition.
In order to create a boot medium, I followed the section "Manual Approach" in [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick).
Newer Ubuntu images do not boot all the way, which I am relating to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1197451).

The only image I tried that booted all the way is 12.04.
However, in the installation process, I could not manage to proceed past the following dialogue:

[image: Preparing to Install Ubuntu]

After a few moments, instead of the expected next dialogue window, the following is displayed:

[image: some console output]

and then nothing changes.

Is this even related to the Kernel bug, or how do I find out?
How am i supposed to proceed?
Has anyone successfully installed Ubuntu on a Macbook Air 6,2 ?

Comment: This seems like a kernel problem (after searching online), but did you try connecting to internet?

Comment: @Waza_Be for the wifi solution, you need to install the braodcom package for wifi and here is the link http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/bcmwl-kernel-source here is another link for detailed steps: http://www.alexvictorchan.com/2013/05/01/installing-ubuntu-13-04-on-13-macbook-pro-retina-102/

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully installed 12.04 on my MacBook Air 6,2 following this [this guide](http://www.maketecheasier.com/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-in-macbook-air/2012/08/27).

I have installed reFind rather than reFit.

Comment: Wi-fi does not work out of the box, guides can be found to fix it, try tethering by USB for the interem

Comment: I have been searching for wifi fixes, but cannot find anything, except this post.. Maybe you can help and give some links

Comment: @Waza_Be: the new live ubuntu on usb (15.04) has the driver.  you have to enable it by using the "additional drivers" (type it in Dash).  then you can install from the machine booted on the live usb disk.

Answer (score 0):

so after you clicked continue (from the first image) if that (second image) is what you see .. then its probably that you downloaded a bad ISO file .. try re downloading Ubuntu from the official webpage ..

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

and you could follow this tutorial .that is how i installed ubuntu on my MBA 6,2 .
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKrFiJH0UHc

- make sure you download 64-bit version
- i've tried 14.04 as well as 15.10 .. both installed fine ..